# Grab Date Range From Text File

Tags: date, unix, ksh

So I have a fairly simple ksh script on an AIX machine that users at my company use to perform certain tasks. Each time that they use the script an entry is placed in a log file containing information such as `user id, date,` and exactly what they where using the script for. What I need is something I can use to pull from that log file, all entries from the last 7 days.

The date that is placed in the log file is formatted as follows:

```
D=`date "+%m/%d/%C%y%n.
```

Answer (score -1):

may be not very useful answer, but why don't why write in the log Unix time. The time in seconds passed since 1st of January 1970. It will be more convenient for some reports afterwards.

Comment: This should have been a coment, not an answer.